# Python Nested Dictionary to List of Lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, recursion

I know this has already been ask many ways, and I tried to read most of them, but still having trouble...

I have the nested dictionary

```
city = {'centerLatitude': '40',
 'centerLongitude': '-86',
 'listings': {'A Name Here': {'address': 'the address',
                                     'city': 'acity',
                                     'distance': 'AmillionMiles',
                                     'facility_id': '1234',
                                     'latitude': '34',
                                     'longitude': '-86',
                                     'price': 'tooMuch',
                                     'rating': 'supergreat',
                                     'size': "10'xAz'",
                                     'state': 'XY',
                                     'zip': '50505'}}}
```

I have this recursive python function (taken from another post)

```
def grab_children(father):
local_list = []
for key, value in father.iteritems():
    local_list.append(key)
    local_list.extend(grab_children(value))
return local_list
```

Calling the function with

```
print grab_children(city)
```

And I get this error... rather than a list

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    print grab_children(city)
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 5, in grab_children
    local_list.extend(grab_children(value))
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 3, in grab_children
    for key, value in father.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

From the error I thought that there was something going on with the `value` used when the function calls itself again because it looks like it thinks it is a str which yes, has no `.iteritems`, but running it in pieces and printing `type(value)` it is always a dictionary (like it should be).

It works with this dictionary, also taken from another post, and I do not understand what is different about this dictionary.

```
city = {'<Part: 1.1>': {'<Part: 1.1.1>': {'<Part: 1.1.1.1>': {}},
                 '<Part: 1.1.2>': {}},
 '<Part: 1.2>': {'<Part: 1.2.1>': {}, '<Part: 1.2.2>': {}},
 '<Part: 1.3>': {}}
```

My questions are:
Why am I getting this error? How do I over come the error? And if the error is caused by my dictionary being different, how is it different?

Comment: It is not always a dictionary; if it was, you wouldn't be getting that error.  Please show the code and output when you put the `print(type(value))` right above the `local_list.extend()` call.  When that confuses you sufficiently, change `type` to `repr`.

Comment: You're right.

`print grab_children(city)
<type 'str'>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 1, in <module>
    print grab_children(city)
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 6, in grab_children
    local_list.extend(grab_children(value))
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 3, in grab_children
    for key, value in father.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iteritems'`

printing the string rather than print(type(value))
`print grab_children(city) = -86`

So every `value` must be another dictionary. Recommendations around that? Maybe an `If type(value)='dict'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
your function should be changed to check if value is a dict, error  
because you recursive function tries to run iteritems() on a value that isstring. 
if isinstance(value,dict): clause need to be added to this recursive function. 
Otherwise function eventually grabs a string..
         change items() to iteritems() if not python 3

    def grab_children(father):
        local_list = []
        for key, value in father.items():
            local_list.append(key)
            if isinstance(value,dict):
                local_list.extend(grab_children(value))
        return local_list

print(grab_children(city))

['centerLatitude', 'centerLongitude', 'listings', 'A Name Here', 'latitude', 'rating', 'zip', 'longitude', 'facility_id', 'size', 'city', 'distance', 'state', 'address', 'price']
```

Answer (score 3):

Notice in the sample that the "leaves" are all "{}". That is an empty dict.  In your "city" your leaves are strings. To use this function as written, then instead of:

```
city = {'centerLatitude': '40'}
```

You would have to write:

```
city = { 'centerLatitude': { '40' : {} } }
```

etc.

But this question topic says "List of Lists" and that is not what your sample code does. Your sample code returns a single list. So I'm not really sure what you want as output.

Comment: List of list preparing for a MySQL DB table load. The nested dictionary was invaluable in the application code, but not so much for loading the DB, so I am attempting to recursively flatten it.

Comment: Except this code just serializes it. It doesn't create nested lists.  Do you want nested lists, or just a long single list?  What is the target table structure you are trying to load?

Answer (score 0):

You never put a stopping condition. The following retrieves all the keys in all the dictionaries:

```
def grab_children(father):
    local_list = []
    for key, value in father.iteritems():
        local_list.append(key)
        if type(value) is dict:
            local_list.extend(grab_children(value))
    return local_list
```